# Выполнение множества потоков и ожидание их завершения

Tags: java, многопоточность

Необходимо выполнить случайное количество потоков, и обязательно дождаться чтобы они выполнились. И только потом продолжить выполнение основного потока. Вся проблема в том что я не знаю как выполнить данную задачу без `Callable`. Можно использовать только тред и любые виды `Executors`. Так же нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки и разрешена только java 7. Может есть способ как это реализовать?

То есть класс наследующий от `Thread` и где то он запускается со случайным количеством потоков, ждем их завершения, и потом продолжает работу основной поток.

Comment: Интересное сочетание требований, можно использовать `Executor`, но нельзя использовать `Callable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать Future можно?

```
ExecutorService executor = ...;
Collection<Future> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (Runnable task : tasks) {
  results.add(executor.submit(task));
}
for (Future done : results) {
  done.get()
}
```

Comment: Callable нельзя, поток создается при помощи Thread

Comment: Thread implements Runnable.
так же у ExecutorService есть метод который принимает Runnable
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)

поправил свой ответ

Answer (score 5):

Самое элементарное решение - вызвать [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) для всех потоков

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```